# How to read and write into system registry using unity3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine, registry

I have developed a game for both mac and pc.
Can you help me with the code of how to read from and write into system registry using Unity3D.
I am comfortable with Unity Script(Java Script), C#, and Boo Script.

Comment: Why do you need to write to the Registry? Plus if this is for PC and Mac, you know Mac's don't have a Registry...

Comment: Actually I want to publish the game as a trial version. If mac don't have registry the how do I make the trial version for mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to use the [PlayerPrefs](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html) in Unity.

On a Windows machine it will read/write to the registry. On a Mac it will store everything to ~/Library/Preferences/unity.[company name].[product name].plist

Read the full page for a description, but this should suit your needs.

Comment: PlayerPrefs on WIndows does not use registry:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html

Comment: @StepanStulov Please re-read that link you posted (that leads to the same page as the link in the answer). Windows Standalone apps are stored in the registry. Windows Store Apps and Windows phone apps do not.